# Issues redirecting to a new page with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having issues redirecting to the local domain php file I have ready to redirect to named thankyou.php is there anything I am missing from this code that would enable me to do so? I've now done a good amount of research on the issue and not found any discrepancies with what I am doing and what is being recommended that I do.

```html
<?php
    require_once "config.php";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO FormSubmission (fname, lname, address, email, phone, hname, chname, mstatus, bio)
        VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['husband']."','".$_POST['children']."','".$_POST['marstat']."','".$_POST['comment']."')";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)===TRUE){
            header("Location: thankyou.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br><br>" . $link->error;
        }

    }
?>
<div id="nav-bar">
        
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("#nav-bar").load("nav.php");
    });
</script>
<h1>Application for Membership</h1>
<form method="post" formtarget="_blank">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    <br><br>
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <br><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
    <br><br>
    <label for="husband">Husband's Name: (if applicable)</label>
    <input type="text" id="husband" name="husband">
    <br><br>
    <label for="children">Childrens' Names separated with commas: (if applicable)</label>
    <input type="text" id="children" name="children">
    <br><br>

    <label>What is your Marital Status?</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="single" name="marstat" value="Single">
        <label for="single">Single</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="married" name="marstat" value="Married">
        <label for="married">Married</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="widowed" name="marstat" value="Widowed">
        <label for="widowed">Widowed</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="divorced" name="marstat" value="Divorced">
        <label for="divorced">Divorced</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="separated" name="marstat" value="Separated">
        <label for="separated">Separated</label>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <label>Provide a Brief (500 word) Spiritual Biography</label>
    <br><br>
    <label>Checklist of Points:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name="q1" value="q1">
        <label for="q1">Why do you want to be part of this society?</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="q2" value="q2">
        <label for="q2">How do you see the power of beauty working in your life?</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="q3" name="q3" value="q3">
        <label for="q3">What do you do to live a life of modesty?</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="q4" name="q4" value="q4">
        <label for="q4">Where can you grow in showing maternal love to others?</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="q5" name="q5" value="q5">
        <label for="q5">Write out your daily, weekly, monthly and annual prayer schedule.</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="q6" name="q6" value="q6">
        <label for="q6">Explain your personal apostolic commitment.</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="70" name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here..." style="color:#111"></textarea>
    <h2 class="makewhite">Pledge of Commitment</h2>
    <h3>I, <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname"> , being drawn by Almighty God and seeking to live the gift of my femininity more
        fruitfully in the heart of the Catholic Church, voluntarily enroll myself in the Society of Saint
        Lydia. I pledge to be faithful the principals of this Society. I pledge myself to live a life of
        modesty, beauty, and maternity. I pledge to live a life of devout and intimate prayer, being
        faithful to my spiritual commitments. I pledge to live a life of service to the Church and to
        others, being faithful to my apostolic commitments. I pledge to wear the prayer shawl as a
        public witness to my commitment and to share with others about they Society. I will faithfully
        pray for the other members of the society and for the Church.
    </h3>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br/>
    
    
</form>
```

Comment: I was able to complete the desired task of going to another page upon submit of a form using: action="thankyou.php". thanks again for responses

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually submitting anything, so just use a button tag, and get rid of the return true thing. Onclick should only be a location="something".

```
<button onclick="location='https://disneyland.com';">
    Go have fun 
</button>
```

Comment: its for a form, so I think I am submitting something but I'll give it a try. thanks for the response

Comment: Then please make it a little clearer what is it you're trying to do. Submit form, THEN go to thanks.php? In that case, you need 2 steps and between them there's a request to the server. There are many options to do this - simple postback, iframe, ajax, to name a few.

Comment: I expanded on my code and I will change the question accordingly